# audio call via browser, equal to skype

Tags: javascript, php, logic

I was wondering if it is possible to make an audio call with another person using the browser.

I thought of many ways and I could not think, I program in javascript and php, but I think it is not possible

will be possible to create a java application that does this?

if anyone knows please guide me with some logic or if there is already a tutorial on this subject.

Comment: possible but hard... `java applet` can run a `*.exe` file (Phone Dialer or what ever you use) on your server

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I hate the windows server, I think I'll study more about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/demo)!